# Flipping certain bit in an integer (C language)

Tags: c

I'm trying to get my program to work where a certain bit is being flipped. I have this function called `flipbit(int *p, int m)`. The user needs to input a digit and a bit number. Let's say the user gives the number `8` (`00001000`) and the bit number `2`, so the 2nd bit in 8 should be flipped, which becomes `00001010`. How can I program this?

EDIT: I made a stupid mistake, I want to  count starting from 0, so the 2nd bit in 8 flipped is actually `00001100` instead of `00001010`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void flipbit(int *p, int m) {
    int digit;
    digit = *p;

    int bit;
    bit = &m;

    int result;

    //printf("The numbers are %d %d", digit, bit);

    printf("%d", result);
}

int main() {
    int number1;
    int number2;

    printf("Give number and bit: ");
    scanf("%d, %d",&number1, &number2);

    flipbit(&number1, &number2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question has an answer that might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c

Comment: Here's a tip: when developing code, always compile with warnings enabled (e.g., add `-Wall -pedantic` to the command line options). Doing so would have alerted you to the incorrect handling of the second argument to your function.

Comment: Please don't update your code with suggested changes.  That invalidates the existing answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checking your source code, there are mixture between pointer and value.
To comply the call of your flipbit() function with the declaration, the call should be:

```
// first parameter is a pointer and second parameter is a value
flipbit(&number1, number2); // void flipbit(int *p, int m);
```

Inside the flipbit() function, the mixture continues because digit is a value and p is a pointer. The code should be:

```
int digit;

// 'digit' is a value and 'p' is a pointer
digit = p[0]; // 'digit' is the first value pointed by 'p'
```

Same error kind of error with the 'bit' parameter

```
int bit;

// 'bit' is a value and 'm' is a value
bit = m;
```

And the result to flip a bit is the XOR operation.

> the bit number 2, so the 2nd

Due to your specification, you have to shift only of (bit - 1).
So, in your case:
0x0001(or 0000.0000.0000.0001b) << (2 - 1) = 0x0002(or 0000.0000.0000.0010b)

result is 0x0010(or 0000.0000.0000.1000b) XOR 0x0002(or 0000.0000.0000.0010b) = 0x0012(or 0000.0000.0001.0010b).

```
int result;

result = digit ^ (0x0001 << (bit - 1));
```

> Did you enter '9, 1' to comply with the scanf("%d, %d",..) ?

Comment: Why does bit have -1 infront?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I'm trying to run the program. I'm giving the input 9 1, which should give me the output 11, but it gives me output 8. What am I doing wrong? I have updated the code.

Comment: If you do this: `result = digit ^ (1 << (bit));`, `bit` number should be in the range 7 .. 0 for 8 bits.

Comment: @FloppySoftware I'm getting this output: -2147483648

Comment: @Piquard, yes to comply with the scanf. I made a mistake, check my EDIT.

Comment: I found my mistake, I should remove the comma between %d %d in scanf. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Given the bit to flip, you first need to create a mask.  Do that by taking the value `1` and left shifting it by the bit number.

Once you have that mask, use the bitwise XOR operator `^` to flip the bit.

```
int mask = 1 << m;
*p = *p ^ mask;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but shouldn't it be digit = digit ^ mask;?

Comment: @Teuntje Not if you want the result to be visible from the calling function.

Comment: a more compact form is `value ^= (1 << bit_number);`